# Dynamic Controller to Save Multiple Models

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have the "admin" controller. In the `add($model)` function I want to add some data inside the `$model`.

How can I do something like this:

```
$this->$model->save($this->request->data);
```

Is there a better way?

Example:

Add Function

```
function add($model = null){
    if($model != null){
        $this->$model->save($this->request->data);
    }
}
```

GET URL
    http://mysite.com/admin/add/mymodel

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking? If `$model` is `null`, that what model do you actually want to save the data to?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve, it may be that your problem can be solved with a different solution.  Also can you show more of your code than just the one line.  The whole `add()` method would be good

Comment: $model = null if no model was passed via get.